# PHP variables, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: php, arrays, shell, variables, command

There is a PHP script that get's new data using python script.
I'm able to `foreach` and loop and get key2, and value2 for array but unable to get `$address` and `$product` variables to put it into $shell command. What is wrong with my variables?
Just starting to code, it would be helpful if anyone teaches me this.

```
foreach ($gotdata as $key1 => $value1) {
  foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {

    //print " key2: " . $key2 . " value2: ". $value2; 

    $address = "";
    $maker = ""; 

    if($key2 == 'Address'){
      $address = $value2;
      print "address: ".$address; //able to get it on console
    }  
    if($key2 == 'Product'){
      $product = $value2;
      print "product: ".$product; //able to get it on console
    }  
    

    $shell = 'python /opt/getdata.py '.$address.' '.$product;
    print "shell:" . $shell; //not able to get $address and $product 
    // $current = shell_exec($shell);
    // $current = (int)$current;
    // print "current:" . $current;

  }
}
```

This is what the multidimensional array looks like.
The main array is different size every time I run the script. It could be 10 or 14 etc.
The
subarrays on the other hand always have the same six items.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "name01"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(12) "1.1.1.1"
    ["Product"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Current"]=>
    string(3) "111"
    ["DateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2020-09-09 15:03:46"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "name02"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(12) "1.1.1.2"
    ["Product"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Current"]=>
    string(3) "111"
    ["DateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2020-09-09 15:03:46"
  }
```

Comment: $key2 can tbe both adress and Product at the same time so it must loop past and then it resets the values to "" again.

Comment: What do you expect `$address` and `$product` to be after the IF statements? If `$key2` is 'Address', `$address` will be set, but `$product` never will be. And vice versa, if `$key2` is 'Product', then `$product` will be set but `$address` never will be.

Comment: It's much easier to help when you get all parts of a question. Not just the code.

Comment: Share your array also.

Comment: And use else statement for another condition or use switch case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can access the values you want directly from the main loop.

> EDIT: Now that the array has been posted, I'm sure this will work.
> No need to nest loop the array

```
foreach ($gotdata as $key1 => $value1) {
    $shell = 'python /opt/getdata.py '.$value1['Address'] . ' ' . $value1['Product'];
    print "shell:" . $shell; //not able to get $address and $product 
}
```

Nesting a foreach loop is the same as accessing the subarray item.

Comment: @user7431522 no problem! Did you know you can accept answers to show others that the question is solved?

Comment: Already moved on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815919/how-can-i-store-new) maybe you can help there too :)

Answer (score -1):

i do not know what is your desire output. But if you want both values. Try it

```
 foreach ($gotdata as $key1 => $value1) {
 $address = "";
   $product = ""; 
  foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {

    //print " key2: " . $key2 . " value2: ". $value2; 

   

    if($key2 == 'Address'){
      $address = $value2;
      print "address: ".$address; //able to get it on console
    }  
    elseif($key2 == 'Product'){
      $product = $value2;
      print "product: ".$product; //able to get it on console
    }  
    
    if($address!="" && $product!=""){
    $shell = 'python /opt/getdata.py '.$address.' '.$product;
    print "shell:" . $shell; //not able to get $address and $product 
    }
    // $current = shell_exec($shell);
    // $current = (int)$current;
    // print "current:" . $current;

  }
}
```

Also you have not define $product in your code.